# Flutter: How to add two text lines to one button?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Dear Stackoverflow People,

I need to program a button in Flutter as follows:

[image: Button to program]

How can I do that in Flutter?

I have the problem that TextButton() allows only to add "one line of text". However, I need a title and a description with different font sizes within a button. How can this be done?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Text.rich` widget as a `TextButton` child. I tried on [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) online IDE and it works.In `Text.rich` , You can define `List<TextSpan>` children, and add text spans has different Text Styles . My code sample is here:

```
        TextButton(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            primary: Colors.white,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text.rich(
                                TextSpan(
                                      text: 'Hello', // default text style
                                      children: <TextSpan>[
                                                TextSpan(text: ' beautiful\n', style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                                                TextSpan(text: 'world', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                                ],
                                        ),
                                ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give "Column" (with your text) to the "child" property of any button.

in your case OutlinedButton

```
OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text(
        'Language',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
      ),
      Text(
        'Tap To Change',
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

and then you can use the style properties of Test Widget to change their style

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. you can use [Inkwell](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) or [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) Widget

```
   InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            // write here your button pressed function
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Language'),
              subtitle: Text('Tap to change'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own button.

Something like this:

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("text big"),
                Text("text small"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you! But this does not give any "button click animation". Also Inkwell behaves differently than a "normal button"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Text("Language\nTap To Change")
```